# gmverse causes pagebreak too much early in the page

Tags: vertical-spacing, verse, gmverse

When I call the `gmverse` package, it sometimes (I can’t find depending of which criteria) occurs too much early page break after stanzas, and it breaks the general LaTeX  vertical space feing shui with very exaggerated blanks in some pages.

The example I give below is not a real MWE because I can’t isolate a minimal case. There are many cases and the following one is the “minimalistiest” one I can produce. If I add some line or a remove some word, the vertical space could disappear at the point I try to fix, but it appears later in the document :

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{gmverse}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{a5paper}
\begin{document}
\poemtitle{First title}
\begin{verse}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d

a\\
b\\
c\\
d
\end{verse}

\lipsum[1-2]

\poemtitle{second title}
\begin{verse}
a\\
a\\
a
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

And I get this rendering:

[image: Rendering]

So, `gmverse` globally destroys the LaTeX fine vertical space management, and I need it only for french hanging with square bracket and right alignment (like [this](https://pakietomat.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/gmverse.png) )

So alternatively:

How could I get french hanging without `gmverse` package?

OR

Fix the the vertical space management of `gmverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `gmverse` tries to be too smart.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{gmverse}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{a5paper}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpatchcmd{\verse}
    {\penalty10000 \vfil\penalty\betweenstanzaspenalty\vfilneg\relax}
    {\penalty\betweenstanzaspenalty}
    {}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{First title}
\begin{verse}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d

a\\
b\\
c\\
d
\end{verse}

\lipsum[1-2]

\poemtitle{second title}
\begin{verse}
a\\
a\\
a
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

My impression reading the bit of code I removed is that the package is meant for printing just poems. The trick with `\vfil` and `\vfilneg` (which is described in the TeXbook) is difficult to “turn off” and indeed it doesn't in the example you show.

[image]

Comment: So, `gmverse` still break other behaviors elsewhere, but this solution still satisfying. I was expecting a solution for french hanging without `gmverse`, but this one seems fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your MWE without using the `verse` package, just `gmverse`. It seemed to typeset similar to @egreg's answer but with the slight problem that it said that `\poemtitle` was not defined and the titles were left justified in the regular font. Perhaps you could just use `gmverse` and defunine your own `\poemtitle`.